Im looking for a horror movie from the late 80s to 90s?
A teenage girl and het family move into an old house and she meets a young girl who she befriends but turns out to be the ghost of a girl who was thrown over a cliff. The ghost girl posses the teen throught the movie at one point attempting to make the girl committee suicide in her kitchen. I remember other bits an pieces but not sure of their order or if they will help at all... Been Looking for this for years any help would be greatly appreciated.

The movie I found to best suit your description is a movie called "Lady in White". The movie was released in 1988. The movie is about a young boy (Frankie) befriending a little girl ghost(Melissa). The ghost keeps re-enacting her death. I hope this is the movie you have been looking for.



